# How can I brake a paragraph after every time a certain character shows up?

Tags: powershell, split, break, openweathermap

:My Script saves with Out-File some Sentences in a File. But when it saves it its not ordered so i saved the output in a variable and joined the spaces.

```
$weatherInfo -join ""| Out-File C:\Wetterbot\Wetter\$Datum.txt
```

The Variable contains the function from an API of openweathermap and looks like this:

```
$forecastInfo = Write-WeatherForecast -City $place -ApiKey $ApiKey -Units metric -Days $tage 6>&1
```

If i dont join it, it looks like this in the file:

```
Forecast for 
zurich
 next 1 day:
Oct 22
: 
9.285°C
 (☁️ broken clouds)
Oct 23
: 
7.64°C
 (☁️ broken clouds)
```

Now its all in one line like this:

```
Forecast for zurich next 3 days:Oct 22: 9.285°C (☁️ broken clouds)Oct 23: 7.64°C (☁️ broken clouds)Oct 24: 7.94°C (☀️ clear sky)Oct 25: 10.99°C (☁️ few clouds)
```

But I want a break after every forecast so:

```
Forecast for zurich next 3 days:
Oct 22: 9.285°C (☁️ broken clouds)
Oct 23: 7.64°C (☁️ broken clouds)
Oct 24: 7.94°C (☀️ clear sky)
Oct 25: 10.99°C (☁️ few clouds)
```

I already tried with -split but there was this error:
**parsing ")" - Too many )'s.**

I just tried it to split with "Oct" like this:

```
$forecastInfo -join "" -split "Oct"|Out-File C:\Wetterbot\Vorhersage\$Datum.txt
```

And the Output in the File looks like this:

```
Forecast for zurich next 3 days:
 22: 9.155°C (☁️ broken clouds)
 23: 7.64°C (☁️ broken clouds)
 24: 7.94°C (☀️ clear sky)
 25: 10.99°C (☁️ few clouds)
```

Does anyone know why the Oct dissappears and how i can get it back? I would be happy if anybody would help me. Thanks

Comment: If you want an answer the better would be to provide the content of `$weatherInfo` before any transformation, and the desired output in the text file.

Comment: In this case looking for "Oct" and replacing it with "\`nOct" might be sufficient. Depending on locale using `get-date -UFormat "%b"` should work to get the month abbreviation. Modifiying `Write-WeatherForecast` could be easier depending on where it's from.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised an API return text-only information and not Json objects that may be easily converted with `ConvertFrom-Json`. From there, outputing the result with any desired format may be easy. Is there any parameter on `Write-WeatherForecast` to specify the content-type to return ?

Comment: Unfortunately not that i read, the only thing left to do is to bring back the split object so Oct

Comment: `$forecastInfo -join '' -split('\)') -join $(')' + [System.Environment]::NewLine)` (because delimiter for `-split`  is a regex by default).

Comment: oh perfect it does work only the first forecast is in the sameline like this: Forecast for zurich next 3 days:Oct 22: 10.51°C (☁️ broken clouds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a very weird format indeed..

I would go through that file one line at a time and build the header line
(`Forecast for zurich next 3 days:`) and the daily forecast lines like below:

```
$Datum    = Get-Date -Format 'yyyyMMdd HH.mm.ss'  # just guessing here..
$header   = @()
$forecast = @()
$inHeader = $true
# use switch to read and parse the file line-by-line
$result = switch -Regex -File "C:\Wetterbot\Wetter\$Datum.txt" {
    '^[a-z]{3}\s\d+'  { 
        # starting a new daily forecast
        if ($inHeader) { 
            $inHeader = $false
            # output the header line
            $header -join ' '
        }
        if ($forecast.Count) {
            # output the previous day forecast line
            $forecast  -join ' ' -replace ' :', ':'
            $forecast = @()  # clear it for the next lines
        }
        $forecast += $_.Trim()
    }
    # I know you shoud avoid concatenating with `+=`, but since 
    # this concerns only a few items I guess it won't bother that much.
    default { if ($inHeader) { $header += $_.Trim() } else {$forecast += $_.Trim() } }
}
# finish up with the final forecast
if ($forecast.Count) { $result += $forecast -join ' ' -replace ' :', ':'}

# output on screen
$result

# output to (new) text file
$result | Set-Content -Path "C:\Wetterbot\Wetter\$Datum.txt" -Encoding utf8
```

Output:

```
Forecast for zurich next 3 days:
Oct 22: 9.285°C (☁️ broken clouds)
Oct 23: 7.64°C (☁️ broken clouds)
Oct 24: 7.94°C (☀️ clear sky)
Oct 25: 10.99°C (☁️ few clouds)
```